# FTP разные кодировки названий

Tags: java, apache, ftp, кодировка

Использую apache ftp client, но проблема в том, что на FTP файлы с разными кодировками. 
Вот вывод консоли, если я ставлю UTF-8:

```
������� ����� 1951 (3).mp3
������ ���� 1950 (3).mp3
Новогодний Переполох 2017 (1).mp4
Спасти Пушкина 2017.mp4
```

А вот, если cp1251:

```
Высокая горка 1951 (3).mp3
Желтый аист 1950 (3).mp3
РќРѕРІРѕРіРѕРґРЅРёР№ РџРµСЂРµРїРѕР»РѕС… 2017 (1).mp4
РЎРїР°СЃС‚Рё РџСѓС€РєРёРЅР° 2017.mp4
```

Пробовал ещё и ftp4j - такая же история.
Вопрос: как вывести все файлы в адекватном виде?

Comment: Это не лечится. Надо сразу заливать файлы в одной кодировке. Как они вообще туда попали в разных кодировках?

Comment: Переименуйте все файлы в одну кодировку

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Файлы складывают с разных уголков мира, однако filezilla отображает всё адекватно.

Comment: А сервер фтп какой?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Без понятия)